# Restrict user logins to one station

Tags: symfony

Is it possible, in Symfony2, to logout a user that has been logged in one machine, when user logs in another machine?

My User entity has a field that contains the machine identifier where user has logged in last place and I had thought using the login listener to invalidate the previous user's session, but i have no success with it.

¿Have you any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` if user provides correct credentials and then check the machine id.

Take a look for example from my app:

Define your listener as service:

```
services:
    blogjakon.user.authentication_handler:
        class: BlogJakon\UserBundle\ActionListener\AuthenticationHandler
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

security.yml:

```
form_login:
    [...]
    success_handler: blogjakon.user.authentication_handler
```

Listener class:

```
    class AuthenticationHandler extends ContainerAware implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface{

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {

        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');

        $machineIdentifier = $this->container->get('machine.identifier');

        if( $token->getUser()->getMachineId() == $machineIdentifier->getCurrentId() )
        {
            return $templating->renderResponse('yourBundle::logged.html.twig');
        }
        else
        {
            // Update user entity with new machineId and redirect. 
            return $templating->renderResponse('yourBundle::logged-in-new-machine.html.twig');

        }

    }

}
```

Of course service `machine.identifier` is your service that provides functionality to get/generate/check your machine id. You have to implement this service by yourself.

On each request you have to check if user is all the time on the same machine.
You can do it in 2 ways:

1. If you have your own user provider you can implement refreshUser(UserInterface $user) method.
2. Register request listener.

I will show you how to register request listener:

service for this listener:

```
services:
  listener.requestresponse:
    class: My\AwesomeBundle\Listener\MyListener
    arguments: [ @service_container ]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Listener class:

```
class MyListener
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) // this is @service_container
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $securityContex = $this->get('security.context');
        $machineIdentifier = $this->container->get('machine.identifier');

        if( $securityContext>getToken()->getUser()>getMachineId() != $machineIdentifier->getCurrentId() )
            $this->get('security.context')->setToken(NULL);

    }

}
```

This example comes from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471227/symfony2-event-listener-and-getting-access-to-kernel-request-and-response)

Hope it helps.