# Symfony 2 Event Listener And Get URL Parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I have this event listener class :

```
<?php

namespace Vdv\TimesheetsBundle\Event;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UploadListener {

public function __construct($doctrine) {
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}

public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
}

}
```

and this url :

```
http://localhost/vdvinfra/web/app_dev.php/timesheet/add/1/252
```

i want to get some parameters(id's) from that url. 
How can i get it in a event listener class. 
The variable $_GET is empty when i var_dump this...

Thanks!

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow have to be relevant and helpful to more people than just the poster.

Comment: @franssu  "Questions on StackOverflow have to be relevant and helpful to more people than just the poster" - And how would you suggest we define or moderate such a thing in a sane and fair way. And what is "more"? Who decides this "more"? Is it 3? 10 people? Besides, 3K views would make me assume it was helpful to some people, let's say 30 people at a reasonable and arguably generous 1%.

Comment: I agree with @James, i asked this question a long time ago and i'm sure the answers helped some people, it helped me 5 years ago!

Comment: upvoted the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject the `@request_stack` into your event listener like you already did with doctrine:

```
public function __construct($doctrine, $requestStack) {
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

    // access the parameters like this:
    $allParams = $this->request->attributes->all();
    $someParam = $this->request->attributes->get('parameter_name');
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that this is correct or at least that simple. In order to get access to the query parameters you need access to the Request object, That part is correct. But I beleive that you gain access to this object via the service container and it takes a little more configuration than you have explained there. See this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471227/symfony2-event-listener-and-getting-access-to-kernel-request-and-response). Could you elaborate on where the requestStack variable is filled from

Comment: For info on the request stack see http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: I slightly adjusted my answer. ;)